# Python Error when splitting a string - not sure how this is possible

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, split

I am trying to split a string of numbers, and store each number in it's own variable. I've searched google and here for answers, and everyone seems to have the same response, but it will not work for me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Input = '1 2'
x, y = Input.split()
```

The strange thing is that I get the following error:

```
x, y = Input.split()
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When running in interactive mode it works without issue.

I've tried:

- Changing from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6
- Changing to 64 bit Python
- Changing variable names
- Assigning to a list, rather than individual variables. Same error.

I'm at a complete loss as to what's happening to make this not work in a .py file, as opposed to interactive mode. Thoughts?

Comment: Could you show the full traceback error along with the whole code?

Comment: What if you don't assign the result of the split?

Comment: So it doesn't work from script... Are the lines written manually or copy/pasted? If the latter, couldn't it be some _eoln_ mismatch (_Win_: `\r\n`, _Lnx_: `\n`, _Osx_: `\r`)? What _OS_ are you running on?

Comment: So, I was putting this inside a function, and I put the function in curly braces. The weird thing is that when I had the first line just print the split output, it worked. It didn't work with assignment then. I got rid of the curly braces and it works now. That's what I get for switching to python this early in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add comment here but mostly this issue is due to indentation error.
and if you are still facing problem then send some snapshots or try executing below code:

```
input = '1 2 3'
x, y, z = input.split()
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

there is no indentation in any line

Comment: So, I was putting this inside a function, and I put the function in curly braces. The weird thing is that when I had the first line just print the split output, it worked. It didn't work with assignment then. I got rid of the curly braces and it works now. That's what I get for switching to python this early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works fine:

```
Input = '1 2'
a, b = Input.split()

print(a)
```

You must have some multibyte character in the script, which is not seen in the text editor. I believe those characters appear after you copy script from PDF or PowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can use the following.

```
Input = '1 2 3 4 5'
a, *rest, b = Input.split()
print a => 1
print rest => [2, 3, 4]
print b => 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems this works

```
Input = '1 2'
a = Input.split()
x,y = a
```

Comment: Why do you think that works and the code in the question doesn't?

Comment: Well, I've actually ran both codes... Guess this has something to do with the unpacking used in `x,y = Input.split()`, but gotta look into it for exact reason.

Comment: This is quite confusing. At some point, both codes are running well. Can't re-produce the syntax error again.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original code as posted.

Comment: I agree with that, but the same syntax error showed up when I first ran the code @darkstarohio uploaded first time. It was clearly not a indentation syntax error. Guess I'm totally lost in this issue.

Comment: I program more in c# than python. I was putting curly braces around the function I was defining, causing the error. I'm dumb when it's early and I ahven't had my caffeine yet.